# Ansible yml changes quotes

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

Using Ansible, in my role, I have defined a variable (`defaults/main.yml`):

```
someHosts: "[ \"{{ hosts| join(':' + port + '\", \"') }}:{{ port }}\" ]"
```

which basically given `hosts=["host1", "host2"]` and `port=5050` is meant to turn the above into:

```
["host1:5050", "host2:5050"]
```

No I am using it in my jinja2 template file (`*.j2`) with `template` module. My template file has the following line:

```
  hosts => {{ someHosts }}
```

But now after running it I see the following on the actual machine (with `less`):

```
['host1:5050', 'host2:5050']
```

Why on earth and how did it change double quotes to single quotes?

EDIT/ANSWER

Building on @techraf's answer, this is what I came up with:

```
someHosts: "{{ hosts | zip_longest([], fillvalue=':' + port) | map('join') | list | to_json }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why on earth and how did it change double quotes to single quotes?

Because you created a list object not a string; and this is how Jinja2 renders lists of string.

See for yourself by adding:

```
- debug:
    var: someHosts|type_debug
```

You get:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "someHosts|type_debug": "list"
}
```

---

If your question was however, how to get that list in JSON format, then your template should be:

```
hosts => {{ someHosts | to_json }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If using template:

```
[{% for host in groups['mygroup']%}
    "{{ host }}:{{port}}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
 {% endfor %}]
```

All you have to do is to define or replace mygroup with your group.